# What is the difference between "Sort by" and "Order by" in Microsoft Access

Tags: ms-access

This is purely a Microsoft Access Question, it has nothing to do with other databases.

What exactly is the difference between `"ORDER BY"` and `"SORT BY"`?

Answer (score 1):

Nothing. These are just synonyms. Access SQL contains many synonyms.